# Javascript for a textbox to accept 4 numbers and two decimals

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a textbox in my aspx page which should accept only values like 9999.00 where two decimal positions are mandatory. need a javascript for the above functionality please help

```
 function isNumber(evt) {
        try {
            evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;

            if (charCode > 47 && charCode < 58) {
                return true;
            }
            else if (charCode == 46) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert('please enter a number');
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    }
```

This is the code that i have written to validate only numbers are enterred now in the same way only 4 numbers and after that two decimals should be enterred

Comment: You could use a `RegularExpressionValidator`.

Comment: This might help: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: Cant do it i want a javascript

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Regular expression validator

the pattern should be

```
[0-9]{4}[.][0-9]{2}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkStringInput(val){
    var regex= /^\d+\.\d{2}$/;
    if(val.match(regex)===null)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yasin but how can i call this function passing the value of text box??

Comment: You should post what you have tried so far, post some code, so perhaps we can help you.